# CSS specific to OS X Firefox & Chrome

Tags: jquery, css

I'm experiencing some padding issues on Firefox & Chrome within OS X but not Windows or Linux.  What is the best jQuery plugin that I could use for detecting the OS & browser, and then applying CSS rules to that?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a reset-stylesheet would be even better? Something like: http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/

Comment: You don't need a plugin Jquery allows you to detect the browser directly for example if ($.browser.webkit) { alert('chrome!'); } http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: It would be much better to look into fixing what is inconsistent, rather than try to add a fragile hack via JavaScript. What exactly are the padding issues you're having? Can we see a code example, such as in a jsfiddle?